# Android Studios: Unable to create a New File

Tags: android-development

I've been following The *Complete Android Developer Course* in Udemy. I followed the exact steps downloading the same files, I've already downloaded and saved JDK_HOME in the environmental variables with the right path accordingly.

I'm currently using Windows 10 and am not sure whether the files are supported. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: I don't think it's outdated.]

[image: File Name and Path.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of how to use a specific programming tool.

Comment: Please read our [tour] and [help/on-topic].  The later has a link on tool use which will bring you to [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go) which will give you a better idea of the various options for where to ask this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of how to use a specific programming tool.

Answer (score -2):

It has been awhile since I did any android development or used Eclipse for that matter, but your error message looks like you havent set the PATH for Android SDK. Check to see if your SDK's path is selected by going to:

Window -> Preferences -> Android - > Browse for SDK.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601